# FSC : error FS0193: The device is not ready

Tags: f#

My project (net472) builds fine on my regular PC with .
On another PC I get this Error. It points to `line 1 on FSC`. FSC is not a file in my project.
What might be the reason for this?

```
FSC : error FS0193: The device is not ready.
```

VisualStudio.16.Release/16.3.4+29409.12
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752

Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6   16.3.0-beta.19455.1+0422ff293bb2cc722fe5021b85ef50378a9af823
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the fsproj file (new SDK) had a **non existing path** at the App Icon rescource for the exe file.

```
<Win32Resource>D:\Git\XXX\Media\AppIcon.res</Win32Resource>
```

I changed this to a relative path and the build was fine again.

```
<Win32Resource>Media\AppIcon.res</Win32Resource>
```